# Unrecognized tasks in Ant

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I'm solving task related with code coverage analyse using JaCoCo, and I need to describe Ant target to start scanning. Inspite of examples "java" and "junit" tasks highlighted with red color in the following XML:

```
<target name="jacoco" description="Code coverage reporting" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="jacoco.exe">
        <java classname="org.jacoco.examples.HelloJaCoCo" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="./bin"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </jacoco:coverage>
    <jacoco:coverage>
        <junit fork="true" forkmode="once">
            <test name="org.jacoco.examples.HelloJaCoCoTest"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="./bin"/>
            </classpath>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
```

But at the same time "java" and "junit" are recognized in any other task. I'm lack of experience with Ant, so what should I adjust to make these tasks work?

Comment: What is the output of `ant -verbose`? You can edit your question with the output.

Comment: Thank you for reply, the tail of build is the following: BUILD FAILED
C:\...\build.xml:34: Coverage can only be applied on a forked VM

Comment: The error mentions an error on line 34 of build.xml. What code is on that line?

Comment: <jacoco:coverage destfile="jacoco.exe"> It seems I should start JVM in some way? I worked only with Maven previously and didn't know such a problems...

Comment: And what is line 35?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not properly defining the tasks prior to trying to running them.

```
    <project name="Example" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="path_to_jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    ...

    </project>
```

I found this on javacoco's Ant task directory. make sure you are performing this prior to attempting to run those tasks

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I have ommited this part in question - in my real build.xml I have such a taskdef. And it's related to jacoco - but I have a problem with recognizing "java" and "junit" tasks inside "jacoco" task, outside "jacoco" in other tasks they are recognized and work properly.

Comment: can you post the output. it would probably give me more to go off of.

Comment: look higher, comments under my question